# Can't get shape into card view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, interface, shapes

I'm trying to add a little rectangular shape as label inside of a "card" in my app and I'd like to know how to do it via XML.

Here's my progress so far:

1. Created the shape as a drawable resource

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="line" >
    <solid
       android:color="#32b4e4" />
    <size
       android:width="20dp"
       android:height="2dp" />

   </shape>
   ```
2. Import it to my view (got this code from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
       android:background="@drawable/card_bg">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/labelSource0001"
           android:background="@drawable/card_label"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" />



   </RelativeLayout>

   </FrameLayout>
   ```

But nothing happens, I can't see my shape, just my card. I'd like to know what I am doing wrong!

To help visualize what I want to achieve here's an image I made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIYkZ.jpg

Comment: Can you upload an image of what you do get?

Comment: I'll do it by editing this comment as soon as I get home in a few hours.

Comment: results: http://imgur.com/0oJN7Ef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove android:shape="line" line from shape.xml.